# Add replicationRegions to an imported DynamoDB table via CDK?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I have a dynamodb table that was created via console and I want to enable multi-region support by adding to the list of replicationRegions using CDK.

After importing the original table using:

```js
const table = Table.fromTableArn(this, "ImportedTable", "arn:aws:dynamodb...");
```

I realized I did not have access to the tables replicationRegions field as I would when creating new one.
Is there a way add to the list of replicationRegions on an imported dynamodb table using CDK?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but use [cdk import](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-import) instead of `Table.fromTableArn`.

The `fromSomethingArn`-type methods create *read-only* [references](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resource_stack) to an external resource.<sup>*</sup>  You can't use these to modify a resource.  The `ISomething` [interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces) constructs these methods return are useful for things like creating new permissions and targets.

The `cdk import` command is preview functionality to properly import existing resources into a CDK stack.  A DynamoDB Table is a resource type that [supports import operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).  Once this one-time import completes, the "adopting" CDK stack can modify the "imported" table like any other, say, by adding replication regions.

In other words, The CDK can only modify resources it owns.  To make ad-hoc modifications to an existing resource without permanently "adopting" it, use the SDKs instead.

---

* [Earlier versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) of the CDK docs did call these `from...` methods "importing" operations, but have been updated to use the less ambiguous term "referencing".